# openbravo Error for java process while ant smartbuild

Tags: java, linux, openbravo

I am getting this error while smartbuilding my module named `in.pispl.bankslipmodue` and java package name `in.pispl.bankslipmodule.ad_actionButton` and class named `ManualProcessActionHandler`:

> /opt/OpenbravoERP-3.0/openbravo-erp/srcAD/org/openbravo/erpCommon/ad_actionButton/ActionButtonJava_Responser.java:5294: cannot find symbol
>       [javac] symbol  : method execute(org.openbravo.scheduling.ProcessBundle)
>       [javac] location: class in.pispl.bankslipmodule.ad_actionButton.ManualProcessActionHandler
>       [javac]           new in.pispl.bankslipmodule.ad_actionButton.ManualProcessActionHandler().execute(pb);

Comment: try commands `ant compile.complete` and `ant compile.deploy`

Comment: There is a mistake while configuring the process for your button.